# Login script and stmt problems

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I am having trouble the code executes correctly but when I submit with nothing in fields I get that you did not fill out all required fields message but when I submit with text in then I get the same message I do not know why

Also I am having `stmt` problems, I am trying to do a clean login script with `stmt`

**login.inc.php**

```
<?php

$ud = '';
$error = '';
$email = '';
$password = '';

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $error = 'You did not fill out all the required field\'s.';
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            $error = 'No account has the email: ' . $email . '.';
        } else {
            $ud = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($db_id_login, $db_username_login, $db_password_login, $db_email_login);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $password = md5($password);

            if ($password == $db_password_login) {
                // start users session
            } else {
                $error = 'The password is incorrect.';
            }
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Obviously that means that either  `$_POST['password']` or `$_POST['email']` are empty...

Comment: And a general hint: using an md5 hash as password protection is not enough. Though certainly better than storing the plain text password. But an md5 hash offers next to no protection against things like dictionary or simple brute force attacks. You should use a salted hash algorithm. There are ready to use libraries for that out on the internet.

Comment: I'll add secret secondary salt keys with the hash ty

Comment: And it might a html syntax error. Not server side I'll test it out with the error message

Comment: Well, you just have to dump `$_POST` into some logfile once to see what you get. Or you simply use your browsers development console to check what is actually sent.

Comment: I also use reCAPTCHA on my forms so that also helps

Comment: What does a captcha have to do with the issues here?

Comment: I use reCAPTCHA against bruteforce

Comment: Sure, but I still don't see what that has to do with the original question... That does not help against empty post fields.

Comment: You mentioned brute force attacks earlier

Comment: Brute force attack against the database, when stolen from you. Not using your form. It is a very common attack to steel databases from servers to be able to crack them "at home". That is why you should take care to always store passwords as really good, salted hashes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have look at your code, and the main issue was your `if statement` logic in general and your prepared statement order and the way you have written you code. Here is a complete working solution.

I have changed password to plain text just for testing, but you should use better hashing then md5.

No reason to make your `$username` and `$password` empty at the top of the code.

I suggest you to use `required="required"` in input fields and make your email validation in your input field.

The login form can be done in many ways, I have just solved in regards to your code, but I suggest you to look at: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL for inspiration.

I have put my notes inside the code for your orientation.

```
<?php
// db connection
$dbcon_servername = "localhost";
$dbcon_username = "root";
$dbcon_password = "";
$dbcon_database = "dummy";

$conn = new mysqli($dbcon_servername, $dbcon_username, $dbcon_password, $dbcon_database);
if ($conn->connect_error)
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

// login logic

$error = "";

if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    // you can put the input var directly inside mysql real escape
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($email) || empty($password))
    {
        $error = "You did not fill out all the required field\'s.";
    } else
    {
        //sql statement for its own, cleaner and easier for debugging
        $sql = "SELECT `id`,`username`,`password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?";

        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            //check if you get at least one results you have to ensure you
            //do not have double email as account, one way to that
            //making email as key in your database and make email check 
            //mechanism to check for double when registering users.
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1)
            {
                $stmt->bind_result($db_id, $db_username, $db_password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                if ($password == $db_password)
                {
                    // successful login
                    echo "The email address: $email with username $db_username exist in the database" . "<br />";
                    echo "id=$db_id, username=$db_username, password=$db_password \n";
                } else
                {
                    $error = "The password is incorrect";
                }
            } else
            {
                $error = "No account has the email: $email";
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
$conn->close();

?>

<html>
<head><title>Login form</title>
<head>
<body>
<h3>Login form</h3>
<a href="index.php">Click here to main page or some thing else</a></br>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    Enter Email: <input type="text" name="email"/></br>
    Enter Password: <input type="password" name="password"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Register"/>
    <?php echo $error ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks the code works, yea I changed it to I much more secure hash

Comment: Thanks for sharing the prepare and bind maytham